# Execute code whenever a worksheet is added

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list box in a form that on initialization fills that list box with all the names of the current worksheets. I use code like this:

```
For Each wCs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not Right(wCs.Name, 10) = "Eng_Labels" Then
        ListBox3.AddItem wCs.Name
    End If
Next wCs
```

(`Eng_Labels` is a worksheet we use for calculations so we don't want to show that.)

Is there a way to have this code, or something like it, run when a user adds a worksheet? Is there a worksheet_added type of event I can tie this to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your details to the workbook's `NewSheet` event:

[image]

It is executed every time a new sheet is created.

Answer (score 3):

yes, in VBA for the workbook, you can use the `Workbook_NewSheet` event that is executed by Excel every time a new sheet is added to the workbook